# Intentservice in JobScheduler's context

Tags: android, job-scheduling, android-8.0-oreo, android-intentservice, android-8.1-oreo

In our app, we have periodic sync tasks. So we have implemented Job scheduler to fire every sync interval. When the job gets fired, we are starting an intent service and this job gets killed. Intent service starts the 3rd party sync from internet/Server

Questions:

1. Is this design ok for Oreo and Nougat?
2. If the intent service takes few mins to complete, will the system allow?

Ref: [Medium link](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-background-execution-limits-on-android-oreo-ab384762a66c)

Answer (score 0):

If your job inent service depend on network restriciton you need to set **setRequiredNetworkType** as there are some new changes done in oreo developement for job scheduler you shold opt for that part as per your flow please take in to account that

Calling **setRequiredNetworkType** defines network as a strict requirement for your job. If the network requested is not available your job will never run. See setOverrideDeadline(long) to change this behavior. Calling this method will override any requirements previously defined by setRequiredNetwork(NetworkRequest); you typically only want to call one of these methods.

When your job executes in onStartJob(JobParameters), **be sure to use the specific network returned by getNetwork()**, otherwise you'll use the default network which may not meet this constraint.

for more details go to this source of the above answer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setRequiredNetwork(android.net.NetworkRequest)

Comment: But my question is, Should i execute all the sync functions inside onStartJob() or if I Start the intentService will be equivalent to this? BTW, Thanks for the extra info like deadline and getNetwork().